# window.open & close several times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a new window using `window.open();` and I want to close it. So I made this code.

```
$('#open').on('click', function () {
    var win = window.open("", "", "width=400, height=200");
    $newWindow = $(win.document.body);
    // more code
    $newWindow.find('#close').on('click', function () {
        win.close(); // just works once
    });
});
```

And it works good in FF, works just once in Chrome (close button stops working), and does not work on IE11 (just tested v11)...

What am I doing wrong? ie, how to fix this to work cross browser?

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XL7LR/)

Comment: Looks like there's an error logged in the console for IE11: "Exception thrown and not caught"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
$newWindow.html(content);
```

You need to clone the element before you add it to the popup.  Otherwise you are removing the original element and moving it to the new spot.

```
$newWindow.html(content.clone());
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XL7LR/10/

Comment: Aha, good point. That fixes Chrome. Any idea why IE still "doesn't work"? There I don't even see the `close` button

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the main problem! Now I just need to know __[how to make it work on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840660/reach-content-of-new-window-open)__