# reach content of new window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I made a new window

```
var win = window.open("", "", "width=400, height=200");
```

and I want to reach its body with

```
var $windowBody = $(win.document.body);
```

and from there use methods like `.find()`, `.html()`

This works good on FF & Chrome **but not IE**. <sub>Found also a [**related post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17018415/2256325) to this one.</sub>

How to fix this in IE? ie, how to make this work cross browser?

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XL7LR/10/) - notice that the close button never shows up in IE.

Comment: what kind of error do you get from IE?

Comment: @LuisMasuelli, `Exception thrown and not caught`. Added a jsFiddle to the question.

Comment: You need to wait on the `document.ready` state before doing anything to the popup window. JavaScript doesn't wait for completion of previous syntax.

Comment: @Allendar, can you explain more / post a example? Do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/XL7LR/11/ - using a onload event?

Comment: It should be something in that fashion yes. I'm currently not in the vicinity of a Windows PC, so I can't test it at the moment. It seems JSFiddle doesn't play nice with these mechanics. It doesn't show correctly on my MacBook either.

Comment: by adding a script with window.onload in the popup that calls window.opener.onpopuploaded function defined in the main body will get this called? i cant test that i am on a mac and i have no explorer at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code to fix it in IE

```
var content = $('#content');

$('#open').on('click', function () {

    var win = window.open("", "", "width=400, height=200");
    $newWindow = $(win.document.body);    
    $newWindow.html(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);    
    $newWindow.find('#close').on('click', function () {
        win.close();
    });
});
```

or use:

```
var content = $('#content');

// and then 
$newWindow.html(content);
```